# Inline comments in vimrc mappings

Tags: vim

(I've asked the same question on superuser, but realized it wasn't the appropriate page for this question)

I'm cleaning up my .vimrc config and noticed that the section with mappings is excessively sparse due to some mappings having comments (for maintainability and future reference).

The problem is that you can't add a comment on the same line as a mapping, because it will be interpreted as continuation of right-hand side.

Example of current state (sparse):

```
" Do foo
nmap <Leader>f :foo<Return>

" Do bar
nmap <Leader>b :bar<Return>
```

Desired state (wrong!):

```
nmap <Leader>f :foo<Return>  " Do foo
nmap <Leader>b :bar<Return>  " Do bar
```

Is there a nice way of containing comment in the same line as the mapping?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use this method, but be sure to do not include space before `|`, because it will be the part of the mapping:

```
nmap <Leader>f :foo<Return>|  " Do foo
nmap <Leader>b :bar<Return>|  " Do bar
```

The `|` separates commands in *vim*, thus the lines above works like this:

```
nmap <Leader>f :foo<Return>
" Do foo
nmap <Leader>b :bar<Return>
" Do bar
```

If you want to use the `|` char in the mapping itself, then see the help of `map_bar` for additional information:

```
                                                        *map_bar*
Since the '|' character is used to separate a map command from the next
command, you will have to do something special to include  a '|' in {rhs}.
There are three methods:
  use       works when                    example      ~
  <Bar>     '<' is not in 'cpoptions'     :map _l :!ls <Bar> more^M
  \|        'b' is not in 'cpoptions'     :map _l :!ls \| more^M
  ^V|       always, in Vim and Vi         :map _l :!ls ^V| more^M

(here ^V stands for CTRL-V; to get one CTRL-V you have to type it twice; you
cannot use the <> notation "<C-V>" here).

All three work when you use the default setting for 'cpoptions'.

When 'b' is present in 'cpoptions', "\|" will be recognized as a mapping
ending in a '\' and then another command.  This is Vi compatible, but
illogical when compared to other commands.
```

Comment: Wow, what a clever and horrible hack.

Comment: I personally would expect a comment explaining why this works because a quick look would tell me the mapping is wrong. But adding the explanatory comment kinda defeats the purpose.

Comment: fwiw, `:help map-comments` currently says: "It is not possible to put a comment after these commands, because the '"' character is considered to be part of the `{lhs}` or `{rhs}`. However, one can use |", since this starts a new, empty command with a comment." So I guess it's at least documented somewhere...

Answer (score 7):

No, it's impossible.

From `:help map-comments`:

> It is not possible to put a comment after these commands, because the '"'
>   character is considered to be part of the {lhs} or {rhs}.

Comment: Just tried this on 8.0-433 and it works perfectly fine: the comment shows in the .vimrc file and the command works as expected (at least for my simple test: `noremap <Leader>tt :echo 'message'| " test comment`. Unfortunately, the comment doesn't show up on the `:map` listing which is what I would have liked.

Answer (score 0):

For certain commands, inline comments seem to work anyway while making a terminal error sound (since I guess `"`  is a syntax error trying to access an invalid register, from `:help "`)

```
map j gj  " Navigate long lines
```

I would highly recommend putting the comment on its own line or using `|` immediately after the command like the other answers suggest.